# How to Delete a user control through key down event

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a User control which is a label along with a text box. this control will created dynamically in a form. i want to delete this control using delete key press.the Click event is used to focus on the control and keypress method used to trigger the keydown event. Here is my code

```
 private void usereditFieldControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        EditFieldControl editFieldControl = (EditFieldControl)sender;           
        editFieldControl.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Key_pressed);
    }
private void Key_pressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        EditFieldControl editFieldControl = (EditFieldControl)sender;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                editFieldControl.Dispose();                    
            }         
    }
```

Comment: You need to delete it from the editFieldControl.Parent.Controls collection.

Comment: What's the problem when running the code? any error?

Comment: there is no error. but i put a breakpoint to identify. but its not enter into breakpoint when i click the delete button

Comment: I suspect that's because this line needs to be in the method where you create your control: editFieldControl.KeyDown +=

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. "sender" can be cast to the more generic "Control" class:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) {
        Control ctl = (Control)sender; 
        ctl.Dispose(); 
        this.Controls.Remove(ctl); 
    } 
}
```

If your control is created dinamically at runtime, do not forget to add a handler to KeyDown event, with something like this:

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void usereditFieldControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        EditFieldControl editFieldControl = (EditFieldControl)sender;           
        editFieldControl.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Key_pressed);
    }
private void Key_pressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        EditFieldControl editFieldControl = (EditFieldControl)sender;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                //Find control
                 for (int i = 0; i < editFieldControl.Parent.Controls.Count(); i++) {
                 if (editFieldControl.Parent.Controls[i].Name == editFieldControl.Name) {
                 //Unhook events to prevent memory leaks
               editFieldControl.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(Key_pressed);
                 //Remove control from collection 
                editFieldControl.Parent.Controls.RemoveAt[i];
                 break;
                 }         
                 }
      //repaint 
      this.Invalidate();
       }
    }
```

Untested, written on iPhone